# My application doesn't receive data using UdpClient

Tags: c#, dhcp

I have created a very simple application to receive DHCP messages using a UdpClient.

```
UdpState s = new UdpState();
s.u = server;
s.e = ClientEndPoint;

server = new UdpClient();
server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
server.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 67));
server.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), s);

void OnRecieve(IAsyncResult asycnResult)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Got something");

   // Do something
}
```

I have a device that is requesting an IP address and so is sending out a request every 5 seconds etc. OnRecieve never fires and I have double checked by putting a break point at the Console.WriteLine.

To check if it was the connection or PC I downloaded Microsoft Network Monitor and did a capture. This captures the requests perfectly so I know its something to do with my program.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the firewall for the machine configured correctly? Do you receive any other UDP messages you send to yourself using a test client for example?

Comment: Are you sure it's sending a request every 5 seconds on the BOOTP port? (67) that is usually used to request an IP address from DHCP when a computer is booting.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I cannot see the firewall settings as its a works computer and its all set via policies. But if the network monitor app sees the data then surely the firewall is not blocking it? or are you saying that the fire wall could be blocking my app from recieving?

Comment: Your app could be blocked (in that it may not listen on the UDP port) or the firewall could block your machine from actually receiving the packets (which should not be the case if you can see the packets arriving on your machine).

Comment: I get a feeling its the firewall. I just ran the app as an .exe and the firewall popped up saying it was blocking and gave me the option to unblock for the Domain Network and Private Network. So I ticked both but still not receiving data. Then I went into Network and Sharing Centre and noticed the Network was set to Public. I then discover I cannot change this until the network adapter has a default gateway. So I try setting this and as soon as I come out of the adapter properties and go back in the gateway unset again!!

Answer (score 0):

Well

I put the following in a console app

```
      static Boolean done = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object s = new object();


            UdpClient server = new UdpClient(); 
server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true); 
server.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 67)); 
server.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), s);

while (!done) { Thread.Sleep(10); }

        }

        static void OnRecieve(IAsyncResult asycnResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got something");
            done = true;

            // Do something 
        } 
}
```

and after some time it "got something"

I would conclude that either your udpclient isnt waiting - most likely.. as thats why I added the while loop.

Comment: So its still sitting there doing nothing?

Comment: Of course you need the loop, as without the loop the application quits immediately after starting the `BeginReceive` by leaving the main-method. If the application isn't running, it can't receive anything.

Comment: Hence I posted a working snippet, as mine does work. His didnt directly, unless there was "other" code.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I copied and pasted BudFinder's code into a new app (Console App) and ran it. I just get the console sitting there.

Comment: What does NETSTAT say about port 67 while your application is running? Does it show the port as "opened"? What if you run a port scanner against your machine?

Comment: Then you arent recieving anything - it works for me here.. The code isnt the problem, once my console app works you can worry about improving your app, till  then you need to find whats blocking the data